# Sending Email to Multiple Recipients from MySql Recordset

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to send an email to multiple recipients using PHP mail() function.  The email message is simply a reminder that a membership is due to expire so email addresses will come from MySql database query.  There would anywhere from 2-10 at any given time.  I found the following code but it generate errors.  The problem is not with my query as it generates an accurate recordset.  This is the code I have:  Hopefully someone can help.  By the way, I am very much a novice so need easy straight forward explanation.  Thanks in advance:

```
<?php 

$recipients = ("SELECT email FROM tblMembers WHERE search criteria=criteria"); 
$email_list = $db->query($recipients); 
foreach($email_list as $row) { 
$to = $row['email']; 
$subject = "Membership Renewal";
$headers = "From: Membership Coordinator <membership@myaddress.net>\r\n";
$message = "THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL.  PLEASE DO NOT REPLY""\n""etc, etc, etc";
  if ( mail($to,$subject,$headers,$message) ) {
   echo "Email was sent successfully";
   } else {
   echo "Email delivery has failed!";
   }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /data/9/1/42/26/1205515/user/1284694/htdocs/Members/Renewals_Due.php on line 85

Line 85 happens to be: 
if ( mail($to,$subject,$headers,$message) ) {

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, then *$headers* comes after *$message*, so you should just change the order in mail() and be more aware in future.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$message = "THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL.  PLEASE DO NOT REPLY""\n""etc, etc, etc";
```

to

```
$message = "THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL.  PLEASE DO NOT REPLY\netc, etc, etc";
```

There is the syntax error, because " will end the string. You would need a . to concatenate the next string.

But you could also leave the two " out at this point, becase in a double quoted string, PHP will replace \n by a newline character.

Comment: Now I have a new error.  The code is in a for that displays the list of renewals in a dynamic form with repeat region. Before the page would not open at all.  The error message appeared on a white page.  Now the page is opening but I have a new error at the bottom of the page that says"
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /data/9/1/42/26/1205515/user/1284694/htdocs/Members/Renewals_Due.php on line 79

And line 79 is:
$email_list = $db->query($recipients);

Comment: Are you within a function when you call $db->query() ?
Then you need to add "global $db;" before the $db->query() call.

And check if you have loaded the $db class.

Comment: OK.  I have checked all of this.  Now the error says that the foreach argument is invalid.  As in code above, I have: foreach($email_list as $row)

Comment: I don't know your $db class, but I suppose, you have to use it like this:

$email_list = $db->query($recipients);
foreach($row = $db->fetch_array($email_list)) {
[...]

Comment: Nope, not the answer.  Thanks for trying to help but I guess I am in over my head here so I am just going to forget about it for now.  I have code that sends a single email to an address captured in a session variable.  Works great.  I have another page where I want to send an email to multiple addresses based on recordset results.  Sounds like it should be fairly straightforward but despite many, many hours reading and researching, I am no further ahead, so I have to forget it for a while.  Thanks again.